# the DOM doesn't work with me when I try to sort an element

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

here is the file I have. when I try to sort some number it doesn't change and keeps empty

HTML file

```
<tr>
<th>Original array</th>
<td id ="td1">1,5,7,-1,3</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>Sorted Array</th>
<td id="td2"></td>
```

JS file

```
var OriginalArr = document.getElementById("td1").value;
var a =  document.getElementById("td2").value;
a.value = Original.sort();
```

Comment: I do not think `td` elements have a value property you can use. You probably need to use `textContent`, and then convert it to an array before sorting.

Comment: you haven't defined any variable called `Original` in the code you've shown. Perhaps you meant `OriginalArr`, but that isn't an array, so I really don't know what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with this. First of all, most elements do not have a `value` property, only the elements that take input. You seem to be looking for `textContent` in this context.

Another thing is that when you get the text in `td1` it must be converted to an array before you can sort it.

Here is the code with the mentioned problems fixed:

```js
// Get text in td1
var td1Text = document.getElementById("td1").textContent;

// Get array of numbers from text
var OriginalArray = td1Text.split(",").map(function(num){
  return parseInt(num,10);
});

// Get td2
var td2 =  document.getElementById("td2");

// Set td2 to sorted array converted to string
td2.textContent = OriginalArray.sort().toString();
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Original array</th>
<td id ="td1">1,5,7,-1,3</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>Sorted Array</th>
<td id="td2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

One more thing to note is that the `<tr>` tags must be in a `<table>` in order to be properly queried by `getElementById`. Without the table tag, `getElementById` returns `null`.